# Parent component slots inside children component vue 2.x

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slot, slots

I have a modal that have 2 slots, `default slot` and `buttons slot`, in the `default slot` i will set the content of the modal (in this case i will use an alert) and in `buttons slot` i will add some buttons (in this case a delete button).

Now i want to create a `component` that will contain the `alert` and the delete `button` mentioned before. but the `alert` will be in the `default slot` and the `button` in the `buttons slot` of the modal.

If i use the code below in the `modal` component like this, it will show the modal with the alert

```
<modal>
   <template v-slot:default>
      <v-alert type="warning" :value="true">
         ¿Are you sure you want to delete {{ text }}?
      </v-alert>
   </template>
   <template v-slot:buttons>
      <v-btn color="error" @click="clicked">Delete</v-btn>
   </template>
</modal>
```

Now what i want is to be able to just set a component inside the modal like this

```
     <modal :title="title" :show="show" @close="show = false">
         <modal-elim :text="'delete something'"></modal-elim>
     </modal>
```

I want to do this, so i can dynamically change the content of the modal in the future, and reuse the same modal layout.

As you can see the `modal-elim` component will have the `alert` and the `button` shown before, but they must apper in the slots of the `modal` component, i have tried this

```
<template>
    <div>
        <template v-slot:default>
            <v-alert type="warning" :value="true">
                ¿Estas seguro que deseas eliminar {{ text }}?
            </v-alert>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:buttons>
            <v-btn color="error" @click="clicked">Enviar</v-btn>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<template v-slot> can only appear at the root level inside the receiving the component
```

When i trie to wrap the elements inside the slot it throw an error

It is posible to add the parent slot iside the child component?
How can i do that?
How else can i do a workaround this?

in the `ModalElim` component? i have tried this but it throw an error.

Comment: Can you please revised your problem again? I am trying hard to understand!

Comment: i have edited the cuestion,  i just want to reuse the modal, using the modal slots and creating multiples components that can go inside the modal

Comment: So, this can be achieved if you remove your by default model code `<v-alert type="warning" :value="true">
         ¿Are you sure you want to delete {{ text }}?
      </v-alert>` &  `<v-btn color="error" @click="clicked">Delete</v-btn>` from the `modelcomponent` and To make alert model component, pass value for that slot and same with button. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/varit05/v47mx9uh/) for your reference. Let me know if it helps!